# creation of ACI service in azure cloud

Tags: docker, artifactory, azure-container-instances

I am trying to created an ACI service in Azure cloud using an Artifactory image.

> Error message-The image 'xxx-docker/app-foresight/jmeter' in container group 'foresight' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.

Answer (score 0):

This should work successfully when Public Network access to the ACR is available but as soon as this is disabled the ability to pull images by ACI is lost.   An "error" similar to the error below is returned:
The image `remoteacrtest.azurecr.io/testing/alpine:v2` in container group `alpineprivate1` is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.

The registry credentials are correct and the image can be accessed from a VM using docker pull or from an AKS deployment in the same VNet.

Image pull for ACI requires Public Access on ACR to be available.

This limitation is stated in the Azure Documentation for Container Registry Service Endpoints:

> "Only an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster or Azure virtual machine can
> be used as a host to access a container registry using a service
> endpoint. Other Azure services including Azure Container Instances
> aren't supported."

This is not mentioned for Private Endpoints.

The documentation ( [How to guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-using-azure-container-registry) ) for the deployment of ACI from an Azure Container Registry states:
You can't pull images from Azure Container Registry deployed into an Azure Virtual Network at this time.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/193123/azure-aci-with-private-acr-and-selected-public-net.html